# Run a remote bash script on a Mac using PuTTy

Tags: bash, batch-file, remote-access, putty

I want to run a bash script on a mac remotely from a batch script on a windows machine. On Windows I have this:

```
@echo off
echo bash /applications/snowflake/table-updater/test2.sh; exit>tmp_file
putty -ssh User@remote_machine -pw password -m tmp_file
```

And here is test2.sh on the remote machine

```
#!/bin/bash
#  test2.sh
#
#
7za x table-apps.zip -y -o/Applications/snowflake/applications
```

When the batch file runs it logs in successfully, but for some reason fails to run the bash file. However the bash file runs fine from mac terminal, where it unzips the files perfectly. What could be happening here?

Please note test2.sh is actually in Applications/snowflake/table-updater as specified in the batch file. And the tmp file does write fine as well. My aim is to have a script to access a further 10 remote machines with the same directory structure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `plink` instead.  The `exit` is redundant anyhow.

Comment: The shebang says `sh` and yet you run the script with `bash`.  This is harmless, but a rife source of misunderstandings.  Choose one or the other.

Comment: You hardly need a script file on the remote server for a single command, though it may be convenient if it's a command you need to run often.

Comment: It is a command I use often and it will also be used on over 10 seperate macs with the same directory structure. I tried plink with `plink user@remote_machine -pw password applications/snowflake/table-updater/test2.sh` and the command still didn't run. changed the shebang and also no result, (now edited).

Comment: You seem to lack a leading slash before `applications`.

Comment: Ah yes that was a typo, I get an error saying `7za command not found` which Ive been getting using the putty method as well. Does Putty have limitations? Should I use WinSCP?

Comment: They are different programs for different purposes. The problem is that a noninteractive `ssh` gets a reduced environment. Try setting an explicit `PATH` in `test2.sh` to make sure `7za` is properly found.

Comment: This is a bit mad. Ive written this `ZIP_PATH=/Applications/snowflake/table-updater/7za` and `$ZIP_PATH x table-apps.zip -y -o/Applications/snowflake/applications` in the bash now, and although both lines work in terminal I get the error, "no such file or directory"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105023/discussion-between-eggfoot-and-tripleee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard program which resembles the scriptable Unix command `ssh` in the PuTTy suite is called `plink`, and would probably be the recommended tool here.  The `putty` program adds a substantial terminal emulation layer which is unnecessary for noninteractive scripting (drawing of terminal windows, managing their layout, cursor addressing, fonts, etc) and it lacks the simple feature to specify a command directly as an argument.

```
plink user@remote_machine -pw password /Applications/snowflake/table-updater/test2.sh
```

From your comments, it appears that the problem is actually in your script, not in how you are connecting.  If you get `7za: command not found` your script is being executed successfully, but fails because of a `PATH` problem.

At the prompt, any command you execute will receive a copy of your interactive environment. A self-sufficient script should take care to set up the environment for itself if it needs resources from non-standard locations.  In your case, I would add the following before the `7za` invocation:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/snowflake/table-updater
```

which augments the standard `PATH` with the location where you apparently have `7za` installed. (Any standard installation will take precedence, because we are adding the nonstandard directory at the *end* of the `PATH` -- add in front if you want the opposite behavior.)

In the general case, if there are other settings in your interactive `.bashrc` (or similar shell startup file) which needs to be set up in order for the script to work, the script needs to set this up one way or another. For troubleshooting, a quick and dirty fix is to add `. /Users/you/.bashrc` at the top of the script (where `/Users/you` should obviously be replaced with the real path to your home directory); but for proper operation, the script itself should contain the code it needs, and mustn't depend on an individual user's personal settings file (which could change without notice anyway).

Comment: If this doesn't resolve your issue completely, consider whether you should post a new question with other / better details, or whether you can edit the current question without putting it too far out of whack with what this answer relates to.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I appended PATH and also set the location of 7za to a variable in my script and it all worked fine.